# I'm trying to import a txt file as a dictionary and am getting errors

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

The file being read contains:

Jul 9762

Dec 2497

May 2429

Mar 1073

Apr 3463

Oct 6735

Aug 15578

Jun 4324

Feb 4176

Nov 88

Jan 15293

Sep 2437

below is the FileIO method.

```py
FILENAME = "monthly_sales.txt"

def writeToFile(myDict):
    with open(FILENAME, 'w') as file:
        for key,value in myDict.items():
            string = (str(key) +"\t"+ str(value) +"\n")
            file.write(string)
        

def readFromFile():
    with open(FILENAME, 'r', newline="") as file:
        myDict = {}
        for line in file:
            key, value = line.split()
            myDict[key] = value.split()
        print(myDict)
            
    return myDict
```

below is the program minus a few things

```py
import FileIO as IO

def Monthly(mSales):
    for row in mSales.values():
        key = row[0]
        value = row[1]
        print(mSales[key] + '\t' + mSales[value])
    print()    


def main():
    
    monthlySales = {}
    monthlySales = IO.readFromFile()
    print("Monthly Sales Dictionary")
    print("")
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("monthly - View monthly sales")
    print("yearly  - View yearly summary")
    print("edit    - Edit sales for a month")
    print("leave   - Exit program")
    print("")

    while True:
        command = input("Command: ")
        #if statements correlating to command functions
        if command == 'monthly':
            Monthly(monthlySales)
        elif command == 'yearly':
            Yearly(monthlySales)
        elif command == 'edit':
            monthlySales = Edit(monthlySales)
        elif command not in commands:
            print("Invalid command.")
        elif command == 'leave':
            print("Bye!")
            break 





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Giving the 'monthly' command spits out: 'IndexError: list index out of range'

I haven't begun changing the Yearly and Edit functions but any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post a [example], and the full error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question, [make an attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem, and then ask a *specific* question. As it stands you are not even asking a question.

Comment: As a specific pointer on the debugging effort: what exactly do you expect `for row in mSales.values():` to do? What do you expect `key = row[0]` to do? Now, *check* that. Is `mSales.values()` what you wanted to use? (If you're confused, check the documentation.)